WSO2 URL download components is replaced?
I have pipelines in gitlab that download wso2 components from this url's
https://wso2.com/products/previous-products
https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/5.0.0/wso2esb-5.0.0.zip
But this URL's is not resolved. Does anyone know if it was moved to another location?
Below is the command docker used to download the files
RUN curl https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/5.0.0/wso2esb-5.0.0.zip\
-H 'Referer: https://wso2.com/products/previous-products' 
--compressed > $(basename https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/5.0.0/wso2esb-5.0.0.zip) 
&& unzip -qq $(basename https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/5.0.0/wso2esb-5.0.0.zip\)
Below error that occurs when trying to unzip the file
unzip: short read
The command '/bin/sh -c curl ${wso2_component_url}   -H 'Referer: https://wso2.com/products/previous-products'   --compressed > $(basename ${wso2_component_url})   && unzip -qq $(basename ${wso2_component_url}) && mv wso2${wso2_component}-${wso2_component_version} ${wso2_component}   && rm wso2${wso2_component}-${wso2_component_version}.zip   && chown -R wso2:wso2 ${wso2_component_directory}/${wso2_component} && mkdir -p /var/log/wso2/${wso2_component}/' returned a non-zero code: 1
Any help will be greatly accepted.

This could be a temporary outage, since ESB 5.0.0 is a 10-year-old product there is no reason for WSO2 to host it anymore. Apart from that this is a very bad design, pulling the runtime from an external website.
